# Java: multiply generic Number without changing its type

Tags: java, math, numbers

Is there a way in Java to implement this method?

```
public static <T extends Number> T doubleOf(T number){
    //I don't know...
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in other answers, there is no general solution.
Beside others, the operation you want to implement may not be well defined for some `Number` subclasses. For instance, what is the multiple of `AtomicInteger`? Is it the same instance with a multiplied value? Or a new instance of `AtomicInteger`? Or a new plain `Integer`? Theoretically, there might be a subclass of `Number` that does not allow to create new instances freely.

You may test the input for some known subclasses and implement the operation for those. Something like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <N extends Number> N multiply(N number, int multiplier) {
    Class<? extends Number> cls = number.getClass();
    if (cls == Integer.class) {
        return (N) Integer.valueOf(number.intValue() * multiplier);
    }
    if (cls == Long.class) {
        return (N) Long.valueOf(number.longValue() * multiplier);
    }
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("unknown class: " + cls);
}
```

I am afraid the suppression of warnings will be necessary, in some form.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is not possible in Java because you can't instantiate an object of type T.

See this section of the Java generics tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createObjects

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late, but today i had this same problem.

My solution:

```
public Number multiply(Number number, int multiplier) {
    return new Number() {
        @Override
        public long longValue() {
            return number.longValue() * multiplier;
        }

        @Override
        public int intValue() {
            return number.intValue() * multiplier;
        }

        @Override
        public float floatValue() {
            return number.floatValue() * multiplier;
        }

        @Override
        public double doubleValue() {
            return number.doubleValue() * multiplier;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: good solution, but you are actually changing the type.
Question was so long ago that I don't even remember why I need this :D

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is no. `Number` have no appropriate methods.

But as long as `Number` have several well known implementation you can just implement it for all of them. Of course if someone create new one you implementation will fail but it is very unlikely

```
public static <T extends Number> T doubleOf(T number){
    if(number instanceOf Integer){
        return (T)(Object)number.intValue()*2;
    } ... and so on
}
```

Comment: Cast it to `Object` first :)

Answer (score 0):

Although a bit weird, you could use the following:

```
public static <T extends Number & Multipliable> T doubleOf(T number)
{

}

interface Multipliable<T extends Number>
{
    T multiply(Number number);
}

class MyDouble extends Number implements Multipliable<MyDouble>
{

    Double  d;

    public MyDouble(final double d)
    {
        this.d = new Double(d);
    }

    @Override
    public MyDouble multiply(Number number)
    {
        return new MyDouble(d.doubleValue() * number.doubleValue());
    }

    @Override
    public double doubleValue()
    {
        return d.doubleValue();
    }

    @Override
    public float floatValue()
    {
        return d.floatValue();
    }

    @Override
    public int intValue()
    {
        return d.intValue();
    }

    @Override
    public long longValue()
    {
        return d.longValue();
    }

}
```

This could be used like this:

```
MyDouble result = new MyDouble(2d).multiply(new Short((short) 1));
```